# What is a ger's birthday in terms of Jewish astrology? conversion date or birth date?

Tags: calendar, conversion-to-judaism, mysticism-kabbalah, pregnancy-birth, astrology

In terms of Jewish astrological signs and influences on people, per Kabbalah, would a ger use their actual 'birth' date or their date of conversion which is considered a rebirth?

Comment: jsa, thanks for the interesting question, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. You *may* also wish to [edit] into your question support for your assertion that, per _kabala_, birthdates are important, since without that assertion, the question is groundless.

Comment: The idea that birthdays have significance is not only based on Kabbala.

Answer (score 3):

first I would like to make a comment about your use of the word astrology. G-d's blessing to the Jewish people includes within it the idea that the Jeiwsh peopleare above being influenced by astrology and that instead our helpand success comes directly from G-d.

There are two seperateideas in regards to a converts age. For all practical implications a conver is the age they are however the day in which the conversion happens is like a birth in the sense that a new aspect of the serson has been revealed that was not before the conversion happened (similar to an actual birth when a child within the mother is revealed to the world) in this sense the convert is like a newborn. Many who say tehillim after shachris say their tehillim which they know based on their age plus one will say the psalm corresponding to the new aspect of their spiritual identity.

in terms of marriage, putting on tefillin, etc you are the age by which you are known to be physically.

Comment: Dude... most reishonim learn jews are only above mazal means you can change it with tefila and zchusim. But stam jews are under the mazal.