# When is a convert's Hebrew birthday?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, calendar, pregnancy-birth

Is it their conversion date, the Hebrew date on which they were biologically born, or something else? (For questions of halachic age as well as mystical significance)

Comment: Regarding what does it matter their birthday? Bar/Bat mitzvah? Someone who converts at 11 doesn't have to wait until 24 to be obligated in mitzvos midoraisa

Comment: @robev I thought that they are obligated immediately. But, if it is as you say, then based on OP's question, when would s/he have the Bar / Bat Mitxvah date? Sounds like a valid Q to me.

Comment: Seconding @robev What is a "Hebrew Birthday"? Is this some sort of halakhic concept? If its just a day you eat cake. he/she could do so anytime. Please clarify what you mean, to make this answerable.

Comment: @DanF they are obligated at 12/13 like anyone else. If their birthday was when they converted, and we take כתינוק שנולד דמי to the extreme, they should wait another 12/13 years

Comment: @mevaqesh Arguably it is a mystical concept, and there is potential halachic significance in every matter involving age. Also see here (as it looks like you have): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59074/things-to-do-on-ones-hebrew-birthday

Comment: There is also potential halakhic significance to one's favorite color. If by potential you mean that you dont know if there is. || Nothing in the linked post indicates that there is any halakhic significance. || Regardless, your intent should be clarified in the question; not comments.

Comment: @DanF They're obligated at 12/13, but I believe they have to reaffirm their commitment to Judaism at that point, as a katan doesn't have da'as. Based on that Halacha (if I can track it down I'll post an answer) it would seem to go by their biological birthday.

Comment: @mevaqesh Vast numbers of concepts in halacha depend on age; I know of none that depend on favorite color. || no comment || Rereading your first comment, I have edited a bisel

Comment: @mevaqesh While it might be strictly more accurate (and less readily conflated with cake) to say "birth date" in the title, I figured people might be more likely to search for the fixed phrase "Hebrew birthday"

Comment: @sah how many concepts depend on age? I can think of very few.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33314/what-is-a-gers-birthday-in-terms-of-jewish-astrology-conversion-date-or-birth

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe if someone pledges his worth to the Temple?  50 vs 15 shekels.

Comment: @mevakesh, even if a birthday is a day you beat cake, it is still of halachic significance. E.g. if his birthday falls on Pesach or Yom Kippur, do we push off the birthday or do we push off Yom Kippur?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2015/02/10/birthday-of-ger/) answers,

> Although a Ger is considered to be “born anew” when becoming Jewish,
>   this is a halachic concept that relates to family relationship and the
>   like, and it is not a “biological fact.”
>
> The Ger’s birthday thus remains the date that he was physically born
>   on.
>
> Note that there is no actual halachic significance to a person’s
>   birthday, other than determining his age, which is important only for
>   a bar or bat-mitzvah. For this purpose the date of birth is of course
>   the “birthday.”

Interestingly enough, they seem to [write](http://dinonline.org/2017/01/22/birthday-and-name-for-a-ger/) in a different answer that the main birthday is when the ger receives his neshama:

> Q: When does a ger celebrating his Jewish birthday – on the Jewish date of his birth or on the Jewish date of his giyur?
>                         A: He can celebrate both. One day to thank H-shem for giving him his
>   neshoma, and this is surely the main birthday, however he can also
>   celebrate on the day that H-shem gave him his physical body.

Comment: So, apparently no Bar or Bat Mitzvah, unless the conversion was as a child? (before age 12 or 13)

Comment: "which is important only for a bar or bat-mitzvah" There's also other potential ages of majority viz-a-viz Aylonit etc.

Comment: "which is important only for a bar or bat-mitzvah": perhaps also important for the rule of מפני שיבה תקום?